# Is there one word for "fade in, fade out"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there one word for the meaning of "fade in, fade out"?

For example,

> A scene on the TV fades in, and it fades out.

From [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fade+out)

> Phrasal Verbs:
>
> **fade in**
> To appear or cause to appear gradually from silence or darkness, especially as a transition in a cinematic work, audio recording, or performance.
>
> **fade out**
> To diminish gradually to silence or darkness, especially as a transition in a cinematic work, audio recording, or performance.

I want to know the one word for expressing the phenomenon.

Comment: *[briefly] **materialises**?*

Comment: I want to say *transitions*. However, that doesn't imply "two opposite transitions." (Nor what type of transition.) And something like *oscillates* is not only wrong in itself but it doesn't imply stopping at doing it only twice. *Transitory*, *temporary*? (But neither implies fading . . .)

Comment: Can you clarify how you want to use the term? In your example, do you mean the scene fades in and then immediately fades out, or the scene fades in, there's some action, and then it fades out? Or maybe one scene fades in as a different scene fades out?

Comment: @1006a I'm sorry for late.one scene fades in and the same scene fades out.In fact,I need this Word for naming to function's name in programming language.I have been searching the appropriate name.I have already accepted one answer,though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to one scene fading out and another fading in in its place?  If so, for video, that is called a ***dissolve***.  [Wikipedia describes it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissolve_(filmmaking)) as:

> ... a gradual transition from one image to another.  [...]  A dissolve overlaps two shots for the duration of the effect, usually at the end of one scene and the beginning of the next.

The Oxford Living Dictionaries concur:

> ***[dissolve](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dissolve)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> An act or instance of moving gradually from one image or scene in a film to another.
>
> *‘the alternatives to a cut are fades or dissolves’*

In the audio world, that's typically called a ***cross-fade***.  Per the Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> ***[cross-fade](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cross-fade)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> (in sound or film editing) make a picture or sound appear or be heard gradually as another disappears or becomes silent.
>
> *‘there's some imaginative use of cross-fading’*
>
> **NOUN**
>
> An instance of cross-fading.

If you're thinking of one scene fading out and then the same scene fading in, I'm not sure what that would be called other than to ***pulse***:

> ***[pulse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pulse)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> 1. *[no object]* Throb rhythmically; pulsate.
>
>    *‘a knot of muscles at the side of his jaw pulsed’*

Although I suspect folks would understand ***fade in and out*** much better.

Comment: Actually, *dissolve* is a more common term; *crossfade* is typically used in sound work. But it seems OP is describing something else (a single scene fading in and out).

Comment: Isn't _dissolve_ more just the fade out part?  I'm more of a photo guy than a video guy, but in the limited (consumer level) video work I've done, I thought such a transition was called cross-fading.

Comment: No, it describes the dissolve of one scene (or image) to another. The *fade out* (audio)  is typically called *fade to black* in video. To be fair, if you say *crossfade* instead of *dissolve* you will be understood - but it's not common (with possible exception in some localized markets).

Comment: @michael.hor257k -- I've updated my answer to include _dissolve_ per your suggestion; I hope that's kosher.  Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: I discovered a possible word here:[https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/phonon/Phonon.VolumeFaderEffect.html?highlight=fade#PySide.phonon.PySide.phonon.Phonon.VolumeFaderEffect.fadeCurve]. I think it is a new word:fadecurve.